# How to disable Win10 'finish setting up' logon prompt?

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows10 1909  and occasionally at log on I get the aforementioned prompt, that I have to skip past before Windows will continue, and want to get rid of it.

Several guides say:
Open the Settings app.
Navigate to System > Notifications & actions.
On the right, turn off (uncheck) the option Suggest ways I can finish setting up my device to get the most out of Windows.

Yet my page does not have this setting. Instead it has a "Show me the Windows welcome experience after updates and occasionally when I sign in, to highlight what’s new and suggested" option, which I unchecked a while ago in my first attempt to get rid of this logon screen.

So, has this option been moved somewhere else in build 1909 ?

Or is it there and I am missing it? In which case, a precise location would be appreciated.

Or is there another way altogether to get rid of this prompt?

Comment: That setting was added in Windows 10 2004.

Comment: You probably should determine what needs finishing. Printers are notorious (here) for causing that. But once everything is properly installed (good thing to do) that prompt does not come up V1903, 1909, 2004 and Next (Insider).  Hiding the prompt may not be the best thing to do.

Comment: The official support document is outdate for this as well: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-off-notifications-about-device-setup-c88f6943-d169-23ca-5f3f-c6b927509e79